# Where is the phonegap.js file for PhoneGap 3.0?

Tags: cordova

When I user phonegap create my-app to create an application I don't see phonegap.js anywhere, but it's referenced in index.html.

How do I get phonegap.js? I read something about it being created on the first run of the www folder or something but that, but that's ridiculous...isn't it? And besides, I've done that and no phonegap.js.

Comment: phonegap is renamed to cordova, maybe there is a bug when creating a new project that they include phonegap.js instead of cordova.js.

Answer (score 5):

Try to build your app first, for example with:

`phonegap build android`

Then the phonegap.js should be in:

`/path/to/my-app/platforms/android/assets/www`

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is a phonegap.js file that must be auto-generated. It exists in XCode's DerivedData folder. We were getting errors when working out of the browser and this would be the reason :s

It would be nice if they would explain that somehwhere.